# Synology NAS resume rsync backup after connection loss

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, nas, rsync

I am trying to do a backup from a synology NAS to an offsite NAS. I am using rsync through DSM5 as of now, but it doesn't give me the possibility to resume the backup if a connection loss occurs. This happens sometimes during the night, as the provider resets the connection. Some of the daily backups contain big amounts of data and are regularly interrupted by this.

[Resume rsync over SSH after broken connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/302842/resume-rsync-over-ssh-after-broken-connection)
I found this answer so far, but am unsure how to implement it on the NAS? I assume I have to SSH into it and modify the parameters of the rsync job, but that is all I know.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: What is DSM5? where do you start your rsync from?