# How can I make rsync work on a bad internet connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, rsync, internet-speed

I'm in a country with a really bad internet connection.
I try to delete files on my laptop that have already been transferred to a server with the following command line:

```
rsync -aic --existing --remove-source-files ~/MyFolder/ MyServer:/MyFolder/
```

but the transfer keeps being interrupted by the bad internet connection.
How can I make rsync work on a bad internet connection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resume rsync over SSH after broken connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/302842/resume-rsync-over-ssh-after-broken-connection)

Comment: @J.Mini I don't think so, I don't see --timeout=60 --partial make a difference here for example

Comment: I wonder if this is an XY question - If your connection keeps being interrupted, wouldn't you be better off making the connection more reliable - eg running it over a UDP VPN.  (I've had sessions running over a VPN where I suspended my device, flew 3 hours, unsuspended my device in a different location  and my sessions continued uninterrupted because the VPN was overlaying a more stable connection across one that clearly broke - and kept the same IP's)

Comment: @davidgo What option did you use with rsync to be able to make the sessions continue after an interruption of 3 hours? I will try to use a VPN.

Comment: I didnt use any options. I'm floating the idea of adding a vpn layer (I used openvpn) so that from tsyncs pov the endpoint ip's /ports dont close/change when the underlying connection resets.

Comment: Fractale, read davidgo's comment again, I feel you misunderstood what they were saying, and their suggestion is worth considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a VPN allowed the connection to not be interrupted as much as before.